# How to change Image > View Center hotkey from "Numpad ." to something else?

Tags: interface

In the past I've frequently used "Numpad ." to center the scene on the selected object in Layout view. However I'm am now using the numpad to emulate mouse buttons, so "Numpad ." no longer centers the scene. The problem is that when I change this keyboard mapping to another key (via Preferences > Keymap > Image > View Center), it doesn't work.

It doesn't matter what hotkey I change View Center to, or whether it includes Alt or Shift or Ctrl, the hotkey only works when it's set to the default "Numpad ."

I've set Preferences > Input > Keyboard to "Emulate Numpad," but that only relocates the numpad number keys.

Am I missing a step? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Blender 2.93.5

Windows 10 Home v2004 OS build 19043.1288 v21H1

Answer (score 0):

Never could figure this out in Blender, but I've implemented a workaround: My keyboard (Logictech G910) allows me to assign macros to certain keys, so I programmed a single key press to do the following:

NumLock > Numpad . > NumLock

NumLock toggles the mouse button keypad emulation (a built-in Windows 10 feature). Works like a charm.